# What is the difference between CHECK and CONSTRAINT CHECK?

Tags: sql-server, constraint, check-constraints

is there any difference between the follow exemples?

```
ProjNum int 
    CONSTRAINT nn_ProjNum NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT C_ProjNum CHECK (ProjNum >= 10)
```

and

```
ProjNum int NOT NULL 
    CHECK (ProjNum >= 10)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I could be wrong but I think the difference here is that a CHECK constraint limits the values that can be accepted by a column where CONSTRAINT limits the values that can be accepted in a table.

Comment: There is no difference in SQL Server between those two statement.  Each results in NOT NULL column (not a constraint) with a single check constraint.  The only difference is that second one results in a system-named check constraint, something like 'CK__t__ProjNum__4AB81AF0'.

Comment: If you can, avoid at all costs system named constraints! A user ringing support with an error containing the string `'CK__t__ProjNum__4AB81AF0` is likely to be waiting a while ("How many underscores... err... spell that again please...") whereas with an error like "stock_gt_zero_ck" is much more likely to get a fast (and correct) response! Ahh... the good old days with Oracle system named constraints... <nostalgic tear runs down cheek... :-) ).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference in SQL Server between those two statements. Each results in NOT NULL column (not a constraint) with a single check constraint. The only difference is that second one creates a system-named check constraint, something like 'CK__t__ProjNum__4AB81AF0'.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "(not a constraint)", that it is not stored in the catalog together with other constraints?

Comment: Hope David don't mind me jumping in... NOT NULL isn't implemented with the "constraint syntax" in SQL Server, You just say NULL and NOT NULL. I believe that this is what David means when he says that NOT NULL isn't a constraint. It does constrain what data you can have in the table of course (you can't have NULL. But the language implementation isn't according to the other constraints (PK, FK, CHECK, ...). I believe that in ANSI SQL, you *can* describe NOT NULL using the "constraint syntax" and just saying NOT NULL is a shorthand. But don't hold me on that. :-)

Comment: @TiborKaraszi: SQL Server [does support](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=1a24f079e5e25dc33aa4e3c02154a3c3) the `CONSTRAINT name NOT NULL` syntax, though (for compatibility with other products, perhaps). Of course, given that `NOT NULL` is a column property rather than a constraint in SQL Server, the name is just ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Both are same.

In my understanding ,`CONSTRAINT CHECK` can be define when you add new columns.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.DocExc   
   ADD ColumnD int NULL   
   CONSTRAINT CHK_ColumnD_DocExc   
   CHECK (ColumnD > 10 AND ColumnD < 50);  
GO
```

Also user can provide own constraint name.

But if we have to put check in existing column then

```
 ALTER TABLE dbo.DocExc   
 ADD  CHECK (ExistsColumn > 10 AND ExistsColumn < 50);  
 GO
```

system will provide constraint name here.